# What dilation kernel should be used to "fill" object in image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, motion-detection

I have some python code which uses cv2 to perform motion detection and tracking. However it often detects one object as two or more separate objects. I think this might be due to kernel size. Increasing iterations only makes the white bits larger, instead of filling in the object properly. The line in question is:

**thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=2)**

Where None is, I can input the kernel size. I've attached two pictures, one is the result of a kernel size of 3x3:

[image]

the other 5x5:

[image]

As you can see, neither are successful, and the result is 3 or 4 small boxes drawn over the animal rather than one large one with the correct outline eg:

[image]

How can I determine correct kernel size? Does image resolution matter? I have been doing reading on morphology and just don't really understand it.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: please review [ask] and [mre] and show your code. your dilations appear to do nothing, so there must be a bug in the code. -- why do you post tiny thumbnails?

Comment: What is the distance between the blobs that you want to join? That should be the size of the dilation. It’ll look very ugly. You might want to reconsider earlier steps in your processing to get a better detection.

Comment: Seems there may be a bug in the code as you say. The example object is 300 x 200 pixels in size, I put this in as kernel size for dilation just to see and it was the same result as the above examples. I have no idea what could be wrong - I followed the steps exactly from this resource: https://pyimagesearch.com/2015/05/25/basic-motion-detection-and-tracking-with-python-and-opencv/

Comment: Edit: I have solved it, I was not calling the dilation function correctly: I needed to define kernel not just the size eg np.ones((5,5))